# Making a 'featured image' become the image for a full banner (top of page) image in a blog post?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm new to WP and I am not quite sure how to approach my goal - I'd like to make featured images in blog posts 1920px wide x 350px high that will become full width banner images at the top of the page.

How do I go about that?

Currently I am using pretty simple .css rules that simply position a background image at the top of the page below the navigation with text written over it - but I'd like that to be applied to all blog posts...

How would you tackle this?

Thanks for all direction...

Comment: Please provide more information, such as where exactly you want to show it (top of the page has a lot of meanings) and add some codes, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by having a look at Post Thumbnails and [how to enable them for your theme.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Enabling_Support_for_Post_Thumbnails) You will need this to enable the functionality of setting a featured image for your post. *This page is great for learning lots about how Post Thumbnails in WordPress work, you should really read all of it.*

You will then most likely want to add a new size for your "top banner thumbnails" by using [`add_image_size().`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) This helps you to define new image sizes, which WordPress generates when a file is uploaded. Images can be cropped or resized to fit your size. This takes care of having images which are 1920 x 350 pixels large.

Finally you will have to create some kind of markup, either for a background image or whatever, and will need to output your top banner image. Using [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) or [`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) and passing your new image size as a parameter can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd definitely want to follow @flomei's directions. I'd also like to add that you'll likely want to place your call to `the_post_thumbnaill_url()` in `single.php` or `single-post.php` to apply the changes to all posts.

Making a child theme will also be necessary in this case since you'll be editing template files and you don't want any theme updates to overwrite your changes.

Better yet, find a theme that has what you're looking for as a feature to save yourself the trouble of maintaining custom code.